# Warning for MinGW ld when linked with clang

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, ld, clang++

I am trying to execute a simple c++ program with `clang` as a compile driver and `MinGw ld` as a linker on Windows.

I know that clang on windows looks for MSVC linker `link.exe` , But `link.exe` will not support linker scripts 
So I am trying different options with this simple program main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
std::cout << "hello world";
return 0;
```

}

> > Option 1

```
clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -fuse-ld=lld-link
```

so here I changed the linker with option called `-fuse-ld=lld-link`

when I execute the main.exe I will get the expected output with no problems.

> > Option 2

```
clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -fuse-ld=ld
```

I will get the following error

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: warning: cannot find entry symbol faultlib:libcmt; defaulting to 00401000
```

main.exe is not generated even though those are warnings.

How can I get the executables when linking with `MinGW linker ld`?

Please provide any solutions.

Comment: What do you need linker script for?

Comment: I was just trying every options in clang and gcc for some time